# Which is better, "on" or "in" + place?

Tags: grammar, prepositions

I am sometimes confused the usage of prepositions.

I say, "It happened in the bathroom."

Native speakers of English would say, "It happened on the bathroom."

Is one, both, or none correct? What is the actual difference between "on" and "in"???

Comment: What dialect are these native speakers you are talking about using? "on the bathroom" certainly doesn't seem normal to me.

Comment: Presumably these native speakers are very poor, but also very pretentious. They must be poor if they live in places that have no indoor plumbing and are forced to resort to outhouses; and yet pretentious to affectedly refer to their outhouses as bathrooms. And outhouses are, after all, the only type of bathroom that you can really be _on_. I guess these speakers must also be a bit odd, ’cause who in the blazes ever has things happening on the roof of their outhouse?

Comment: Okay, is there some better way of welcoming a new user than by downvoting?

Comment: They fell on the bathroom? They freshened up on the bathroom? Do you happen to live on an island called Lilliput?

Comment: @leoger, Yuki: I didn't downvote, but I didn't upvote either. Really, questions like this should be asked on [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com/). I only answered because I thought the BrE *in/on the loo/toilet* was interesting, not the actual question as asked (but I'd have been more than happy to upvote *and* answer more extensively if it *had* been asked on ELL)

Comment: @FumbleFinger: Thanks, I didn't know ELL existed! That makes more sense then.

Comment: @leoger: If you go to ELL, you might like to start by looking at how [this question](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/17428/) was originally asked and closed. Follow the link the OP put in a comment to where he then asked a more focussed question. I'm sure you'll agree that the ***second*** question has a couple of excellent answers that will be far more useful to learners than most of the stuff we get here on ELU (where most posters assume most other contributors have a pretty good working knowledge of English).

Answer (score 4):

So far as I'm aware, *no* native speakers would ever say they were ***on*** the bathroom.

OP may be getting confused by the fact that BrE speakers can say...

> ["I'm **in** the loo"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22he%20was%20the%20archetypal%22&tbas=0&biw=1238&bih=906&sa=X&ei=9ar-UoC1L8OS0AWE1IDQAw&ved=0CB8QpwUoBA&source=lnt&tbs=cdr:1,cd_min:1/1/1800,cd_max:12/31/1960&tbm=bks#q=%22I%27m%20in%20the%20loo%22&tbm=bks) *(I'm **in** the room containing the toilet)*
>    ["I'm **on** the loo"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22he%20was%20the%20archetypal%22&tbas=0&biw=1238&bih=906&sa=X&ei=9ar-UoC1L8OS0AWE1IDQAw&ved=0CB8QpwUoBA&source=lnt&tbs=cdr:1,cd_min:1/1/1800,cd_max:12/31/1960&tbm=bks#q=%22I%27m%20on%20the%20loo%22&tbm=bks) *(I'm actually sitting **on** the toilet)*

I don't think there's anything comparable in AmE (except maybe *in/on the toilet*).

In case anyone thinks it's "odd" that I chose to use ***I*** rather than, say, ***he*** there, I'll just say that it would normally be considered extremely bad form to say *"He's on the loo"* (it's always *"in"* there! ).

Comment: in AmE, the toilet is *never* the room that I have ever heard.  So "in the toilet" would mean in the bowl, or possibly the water tank behind it.

Comment: @Oldcat: Yeah, I thought as much. But I find AmE "circumlocutious" references to such facilities very confusing. A few months ago I was astonished to hear for the first time a *very* basic urinal in a bar being called the ***bathroom***. Apart from the urinal and a single wc in a closet without a door, there was just a tap for rinsing hands. And not even a basin under the tap - water just ran across the floor into the urinal sluice. *Bathroom?!!!*

Comment: The problem is that the "device" keeps sucking up the name of the room and applying it to the device itself.  Then we have to rename the room once more.  "Toilet" used to refer to the acts in getting up in the morning, then to the room you did it in, then to the device alone.  The device itself has no name.  And at least it was 'bathroom' and not 'restroom'!  That is not where I rest!!

Comment: @Fumble, _bathroom_ is the generic and inoffensive term for any kind of toilet-like location in AmE. Bath or no bath. It is no less strange that _toilet_ (originally ‘clothes bag’!) is used for either the porcelain device or the room that contains it…

Comment: Now I'm wondering if Americans make more use of euphemisms.

Comment: We may stack them higher in just this case.  In general, my impression is that BrE tends to be less direct than AmE.

Comment: @Susan, Oldcat: I'm sure we all have a bewildering array of eupemisms and not-so-euphemistic slang terms. But estate agents (AmE realtors?) tend to stick to the basics. In the UK they refer to *bathroom* (or *shower* if that's present but there's no bath), or *cloakroom* if neither "whole body wash" facilities are present. Occasionally *toilet* if it's an "upstairs cloakroom", but they're not common these days. Other than that the only one I can think of is *en-suite*, which can only be accessed from one bedroom, and must contain at least a toilet (but perhaps bath and/or shower too).

Comment: @FumbleFingers - Real estate agents here are weird. In the US, "half bath" is one with no bath or shower at all!  And note how "cloakroom" is getting sucked into the black hole of euphemism.  No cloaks there!  The term for the single access (often with no door to the shower area) is a "master bath suite"

Comment: @Susan: It takes a lifetime. Most Brits who live more than 50 miles away from me think of me as a Cockney just because I'm not too far from London. But for the past few years I've had a real Cockney lodger, and there's rarely a day goes by without he comes out with another usage I never heard before. We do [The Guardian Crossword](http://www.theguardian.com/crosswords/cryptic/26183) together most days - and again, I reckon both of us learn at least one new thing about English/General Knowledge from that almost every day.

Comment: @Susan: It was certainly a godsend to me. I'd just lost my job unexpectedly, and at my age the chances of getting another were slim, to say the least (I'd worked from home for years, and had no enthusiasm for going back to 9-5 anyway). So the rent was handy, but the best bit is when he's not being an ageing international rock star going off on tour and giving me a bit of peace and quiet, his *other* forte is he's a trained chef. So I get restaurant-calibre meals cheap, in the comfort of my own home, where I can have an after-dinner fag without going outdoors. *And* he likes crosswords!

Comment: @Susan: He was the regular (but usually, uncredited) keyboard player with [death metal band *Cathedral*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cathedral_(band)) until they called it a day last year, and I can't say I was ever much into that. But he played some great riffs with Bo Diddley on [Bo's The Man! Live On Tour](http://www.raucousrecords.com/rock-and-roll-cds_19/bo-s-the-man--live-on-tour-cd_17150.aspx). It might be old hat now, but that's more *my* kind of music! Here's [unflattering pic](http://www.metal-archives.com/artists/Munch/318144)

Answer (score 1):

Use *in the bathroom*. If something is enclosed by walls or bound by some sort of border, use *in*. You are *in* a country. You are *in* the house. You are *in* college (you are inside the period that starts with enrollment and ends with graduation or dropping out).

*On* usually means positioned above and physically touching something's top part. So if you said *on the bathroom*, you are outside sitting/standing on the roof above your bathroom.

The usage of the prepositions in, on, and at are very tricky for those learning English, especially when their native language has one preposition to denote something's location - whether on, in, or at. Unfortunately, they will have to memorize which of in, on, or at goes with which object.

The usage of in, on, and at gets even more tricky because they are also used beyond describing something's location. Phrases such as "on the house" for freebees, "in my career", or "at 3 PM" must be memorized.

When speaking about time, it's still tricky. We say "in 10 minutes", "at the strike of 12", and "on Tuesday". I'm not aware of any rules for the choice of preposition in these cases. As far as I'm concerned, we needed to learn each prepositional phrase individually.

Comment: I think it's ***in** so many minutes/hours/days* because the figurative reference is to that span of time viewed as a "distance" along a "timeline". Originally, I think *"I'll do it in a week"* meant *within the span of a timeline stretching forward for one week* - but in the nature of such things, everyone opts to do things at the last moment, so nowadays it often means *"I'll start (and perhaps finish) doing it a week from now"*. And it's ***at** [some specific point in time]* because that's a *location* on the timeline, not a *stretch* of it with separate start and end points.

Comment: @FumbleFingers - if it were a stretch of time, you would say "I'll do it **during** that week"

Comment: What about the rules for "on" regarding time?

Comment: @Mickael: It's ***at** [some clock time]*, ***on** [some day]*, and ***in** [some month/year]*. I wouldn't like to say exactly why we move through the prepositions like that, but I'm sure the likes of [John Lawler](http://english.stackexchange.com/users/15299/john-lawler) would know.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I don't know what Prof. Lawler will say, but I'm pretty sure it's because we hold a continuous election and those are the current winners in their respective categories.

Comment: @StoneyB: Oh yeah - I completely agree "time and chance" happeneth to idiomatic preposition usages just as much as they do to us lowly mortals. But what I meant was I expect John could casually identify the specific *figurative* (such things are *always* "figurative") sense that applies with each preposition usage that happens to be the norm today. Not that they're in any sense "inevitable" by virtue of being "**the** logical choice". But I've no doubt they're at least "explicable".