# ON a cul de sac or IN a cul de sac?

Tags: word-choice

I'm writing a short story and was wondering which sentence is grammatically correct.

> We lived in a cul de sac.

Or

> We lived on a cul de sac.

Comment: Related: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/152127/which-is-better-on-or-in-place

Comment: Either is grammatically correct, but to me, as a British English speaker, 'in' would be more idiomatic. I think an American might prefer 'on'.

Comment: Related: http://www.english-test.net/forum/ftopic28827.html

Comment: One doesn't live in a street, so I don't see why one would live in a cul de sac.  "We live on a (or at the) cul de sac at the end of Stirrup Road."  Or, "We live on Stirrup Road, at the cul de sac."  (American English, East Coast)

Comment: Sorry, ab2, and one not just frequently but more often than not does live *in* a street… at least here in the UK

Answer (score 0):

"In" seems to be "more correct" (according to Google definations) :

> "IN" : expressing the situation of something that is or appears to be enclosed or surrounded by something else.
>   "I'm living in London"
>   synonyms:   inside, within, in the middle of, within the bounds/confines of; 
>  
>   "ON" : physically in contact with and supported by (a surface).
>   "on the table was a water jug"
>   2.
>   forming a distinctive or marked part of the surface of.
>   "a scratch on her arm"

Since a cul de sac is enclosed or surrounded by houses, I would choose "in" 
Hope this helps!

Comment: A cul-de-sac is a street. Do you live *in* or *on* a street?

Comment: @PeterShor It's not a street, it's a part of a street. It gets used in sentences similarly to the way "neighborhood" does.

Comment: In Britain a cul-de-sac is a street with access from only one end. http://www.alamy.com/stock-photo/cul-de-sac-sign.html  I've never heard it used in the way Barmar describes.

Answer (score 0):

[Google Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=on%20a%20cul%20de%20sac%2Cin%20a%20cul%20de%20sac&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Con%20a%20cul%20de%20sac%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cin%20a%20cul%20de%20sac%3B%2Cc0) shows that "in" is much more common in isolation.

[image]

But if we add the word that the phrase is modifying, it varies. When talking about a structure like a house, it's "on", presumably because the house physically sits on the land comprising the cul-de-sac. But when talking about an activity such as living, the cul-de-sac is treated as a container, similar to a neighborhood.

[image]

Comment: If you prefix *"in/on a cul-de-sac"* with "house" or "live", they become comparable.  [Consider this Ngram.](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=house+in+a+cul-%2Chouse+on+a+cul-%2Clive+in+a+cul-%2Clive+on+a+cul-&year_start=1930&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=20&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Chouse%20in%20a%20cul%20-%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Chouse%20on%20a%20cul%20-%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Clive%20in%20a%20cul%20-%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Clive%20on%20a%20cul%20-%3B%2Cc0)

Comment: You're right. It looks like it depends on whether we talk about a physical object (the house) versus the activity that takes place there (live).